# is f(x) = 0 irreducible in $\mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let's say I have a polynomial like $$f(x) = 4x^2 +12x +28$$ when I reduce this with respect to `mod 2`; I end up with $0$.

Can I say that zero is irreducible in  $\mathbb{Z} /2 \mathbb{Z}$ so $f(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: Maybe you should factor out the common four and THEN reduce modulo 2.

Comment: Ah yes, I'll try it now.

Comment: No, the zero polynomial is not irreducible. However, you can argue that $x^2+3x+7$ (aka $x^2+1$) is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Remember that the proof about the relationship between irreducibility modulo $p$ and irreducibility in $\mathbb Q$ requires that the first coefficient not go to zero.

Answer (score 1):

An irreducible polynomial is a polynomial of degree $\ge1$ that cannot be factored into two polynomials of degree $\ge 1$. Under this definition, the $0$ polynomial is not irreducible.